# Hide logo on desktops only [wordpress]

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, menu

I am developing a website in WordPress where I am using a nav images plugin to center the logo among the menu items in the header. Essentially, what I would like to do is hide the main logo area (above the header) on desktops/laptops so it the logo is only shown as the nav menu image. I would also like to hide the menu image (which links to home) on the mobile/tablets because it is shown as blank in the navigation menu.

Website is: http://museiam.ca/

**Main Logo:**

```
.gbtr_logo {

}
```

**Logo Nav Menu on mobile:**

```
.menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-2716 has-image {

}
```

I have found the styles here but am unsure how to implement it: http://www.studiopress.com/design/website-respond-mobile-devices.htm

I appreciate any input. Thank you.

Comment: Use media queries (google CSS media query) to apply specific rules when e.g. width is less than 1000px or between 600px and 1000px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries 
//devices withing 768px

```
@media (max-width:768px){

.menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-2716 has-image {
display:none;
}

}
```

Just place this in your theme style.css

Comment: Hi. I got the logo to only show on laptops/desktops but am unable to hide the menu item on phones/tablets. Maybe I'm using wrong class?

Comment: Might be, please check the element correctly and use the selector accordingly. The whole idea is to use media queries

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend this resource to help with HTML CSS and specifically media queries in your case:

[Learn to Code HTML and CSS](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/)